# How to prevent geom_histogram from dropping data when invoking fill= aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, fill

I want to generate a histogram with data of 2 classes (Event=0 vs. Event=1).  In my case I have only one case where Event=0.  The histogram plots correctly if I do not invoke the 'fill=' aesthetic, but drops the Event=0 case when I do invoke 'fill'.  The problem goes away when I scale Y continuous, but I want to use the log10 scale.  To demonstrate (I am using current versions of R, RSTudio, and associated packages):

```
library(ggplot2)

Dur<-c(200,200,200,200,10,20,30)
Event<-c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
a<-data.frame(cbind(Dur,Event))
a$Event1<-as.character(a$Event)

p<-ggplot(data=a,aes(x=Dur,fill=Event1))+
  geom_histogram(color='black')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue"),name='Censor')+
  scale_y_log10()+
  labs(title='Attempt Duration: WAL',x="Duration (s)")
p
```

[image: Dropped value for event=0]
by contrast these plot correctly

```
p<-ggplot(data=a,aes(x=Dur))+
  geom_histogram(color='black')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue"),name='Censor')+
  scale_y_log10()+
  labs(title='Attempt Duration: WAL',x="Duration (s)")
p
```

[image: No fill]

```
p<-ggplot(data=a,aes(x=Dur,fill=Event1))+
  geom_histogram(color='black')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue"),name='Censor')+
  #scale_y_log10()+
  labs(title='Attempt Duration: WAL',x="Duration (s)")
p
```

[image: No log-scale]

Likewise, if I add a second '0' case it all plots correctly.  Ideas?

Comment: logging the y-axis in a histogram doesn't make such sense, if you are trying to show a distribution. Also using log-y scales with bar plots is visually misleading, because the area of the bars is no longer proportional to the values being plotted

Comment: Nate--I understand your point, but actually disagree.  It is very helpful for showing exponential distributions, which linearize under a log scale.   And since ggplot does not allow a broken axis this is what works best for me

Comment: If you need really need a log scale you might be better off building you summary data first and adding a small value, 1, to every bin with zero count then using `geom_col()` to approximate a histogram. Without that ggplot's transformation will introduce -Inf values for each bin with 0 counts, which is the cause of your error message and problems

Comment: No--it is not a zero count--there is a value that I assigned a zero to (so it should have a value of 1).  The zeroed cells are just dropped automatically because (as I understand) of the default state of drop=TRUE.  The problem is that the single observation where 'Event'=0 is being dropped.  Also if I have more than one value where Event=0 then it works.  It appears to be a bug in ggplot2

Comment: To clarify--the first plot indicates that there are only 3 values of 200 when there are actually 4.  This is shown in the second plot where  I removed the 'fill=' aesthetic.  So it appears to be some interplay between fill= and the log scale.  If we add one more 200 with an additional Event value of 0 the whole thing works.

Comment: `ggplot` is doing what you asked it to. If you look at what the `scale_y_log10()` function is doing `data.frame(Dur = c(200,200,200,200,10,20,30),
           Event = as.character(c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1))) %>% 
  group_by(Event, Dur) %>% 
  summarise(n = log10(n()))` you will see that Event==1 for 10, 20, and 30 is in fact 0 because you are taking the log of 1. Same goes for Event==0 since there is a sample of 1.  For Event==1 at 200 you are taking `log10(3)`

Answer (score 1):

'Event'=0 is not being dropped. `log(1)` just equals `0`.

Comment: This is correct---and it touches on why stacked histograms are not recommended with a log scale.  Ideally the total should be logged, and the proportional shading be set to match, scaled appropriately depending on how it is stacked.  In any case this confirms the points made by others that logging histograms is always problematic, and should be avoided altogether for stacked histograms